# MahApps Metro MessageBox styling with CustomResourceDictionary

Tags: wpf, messagebox, mahapps.metro

Trying to control MahApps messagebox / dialog styling but it doesn't work. I have a custom style that defines a different button, e.g.:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
...
</Style>
```

Then I'm using this when opening the messageBox:

```
dialogSettings.CustomResourceDictionary = new ResourceDictionary { Source = new System.Uri("pack://application:,,,/ComponentsProject;component/Themes/Components.MetroMessageBox.xaml") };
var result = await metroWindow.ShowMessageAsync(caption, message, dialogStyle, dialogSettings);
```

But is has no effect on the buttons in the messagebox / dialog what so ever. 
Any pointers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to set the `x:Key` attribute of your `Style` to `AccentedDialogSquareButton`:

```
<Style x:Key="AccentedDialogSquareButton" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    ...
</Style>
```